# Python compare part of string to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have multiple strings that looks like this:

```
“BPBA-SG790-NGTP-W-AU-BUN-3Y”
```

I want to compare the string to my list and if part of the string is in the list, I want to get only the part that is found on the list as a new variable.

This is my code:

```
    mylist = ["770", "790", "1470", "1490"]
    sq = “BPBA-SG790-NGTP-W-AU-BUN-3Y”

    matching = [s for s in mylist if any(xs in s for xs in sq)]
    print(matching)

>>> ['770', '790', '1470', '1490']
```

For example this is what I want to get:

```
    mylist = ["770", "790", "1470", "1490"]
    sq = “BPBA-SG790-NGTP-W-AU-BUN-3Y”

    matching = [s for s in mylist if any(xs in s for xs in sq)]
    print(matching)

>>> 790
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `in` keyword from python:

```
mylist = ["770", "790", "1470", "1490"]
sq = "BPBA-SG790-NGTP-W-AU-BUN-3Y"
for i in mylist:
    if i in sq:
        print(i)
```

The code iterates through the list and prints the list element if it is in the string

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Like this, you can use a list comprehension:

```
mylist = ["770", "790", "1470", "1490"]
sq = "BPBA-SG790-NGTP-W-AU-BUN-3Y"

matching = [m for m in mylist if m in sq]

print(matching)
```

Output:

```
['790']
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I get your question, but the following should do the trick

```
[x for x in mylist if x in sq]
```

It return you with a list of those elements of the list that appears in the string

Answer (score 1):

try

```
mylist = ["770", "790", "1470", "1490"]
sq = "BPBA-SG790-NGTP-W-AU-BUN-3Y"

b = [x for x in mylist if sq.find(x) != -1]
print b
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`[s for s in mylist if s in sq]`

For those who dislike brevity:

This is a list comprehension. It evaluates to a list of strings `s` in `mylist` that satisfy the predicate `s in sq` (i.e., `s` is a substring of `sq`).

Comment: Code-only answer values nothing